# How do I keep a dynamic URL updated?

Tags: linux, bash

I am writing a that will allow me to automate the customization of a fresh Linux installation. The script generally runs

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

for all programs that are in the apt repository, **but I'm here to ask for help about programs that aren't found in a package manager.**

For example, lets say I want to install "IDEA".

Manually I'd

- Go to the Jetbrains website
- Download the appropriate .tar.gz file
- Install said .tar.gz

My question stems from the second step *"Download the appropriate .tar.gz file"*. If I were to download this manually now, I'd use wget against the URL "https://download-cf.jetbrains.com/idea/ideaIU-2016.1.3.tar.gz".

As you can see, the URL changes with each version. **My question is, how would you write a BASH script to always download the newest version of Idea.**

I am also looking into programs like Vagrant and the likes, but still curious to see if there is a solution for this problem.

Comment: First you get the page that contains the link to the download, then you parse it.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams So I looked into that, the URL I download my tar.gz file does not have the the link to download in it. Any other advice on how to proceed? The URL I looked at to parse was "https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/#section=linux"

Comment: Then that's not the page you want to parse.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Alright, then I don't know how to proceed, as that is the exact URL that has the download available. If you see a way to get around this, please let me know. I appreciate your time!

Comment: Did you try clicking on the button that "starts" the download?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I'm not exactly sure I follow, but I ran "inspect" on the download button to "snap" to that location in the source code and didn't see the URL. If I misinterpreted you, could you please clarify?

Comment: The link isn't on that page. At all. Dig deeper.

Comment: The download button is this link: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/download-thanks.html?platform=linux&code=IIC. You need to parse the reply from fetching that link. It contains the download file name.